# Select random number within range as a new column

Tags: r, random

I am trying to create a new column of `values` in a dataframe that would be a random number within a range. As an example:

```
min <- sample(1:10, 10)
max <- sample(11:20, 10)

dt <- data.frame(min=min, max=max)

dt$value <- sample(dt$min:dt$max,1)
```

This gives me an error message.

How would I do this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it gives a warning (not an error) because you're supplying two vectors to the `:` function rather than two numbers. So it's just using the first elements (which will be `2` and `19` in this example). I think this is probably what you're after:

```
dt$value <- sapply(1:nrow(dt), function(x) sample(dt$min[x]:dt$max[x], 1))
```

Or if you're using dplyr, much clearer:

```
dt %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(value = sample(min:max, 1))
```